# UIButton title + image using Paintcode app

Tags: swift, image, uibutton, paintcode

I have a UIButton with title and image onto the right of the title. But i wanna draw the image using paintcode app rather than using image in assets. How can i do it?

Comment: You will need a custom UIButton to do that as PaintCode does not generate a UIImage.

Comment: @the4kman, i do have a custom button but if i add the paintCodeApp generated code in override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {}, it just draws the within the whole button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could either create an reusable widget based on a `.xib` file, which would draw everything you need, for example:

```
Reusable widget (loaded from a .xib)

 _____________________________________________
| UIView                                      | 
|     ___________________________________     |
|    | Button  |  Image (from PaintCode) |    |
|    |_________|_________________________|    |
|_____________________________________________|
```

... or do everything inside PaintCode itself (the image AND the text), like:

[image: wiring]

... which would result in the following:

[image: simulator]

You could even use `@IBInspectable` to set the text of the button directly in **Interface Builder**:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class TextButton: UIButton {

    // MARK: Properties

    // The button's text can be set in Interface Builder.
    @IBInspectable var text: String = "HelloWorld!" {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay() // Forces PaintCode to redraw.
        }
    }

    override var isHighlighted: Bool {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    override var isSelected: Bool {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    override var isEnabled: Bool {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    // MARK: Lifecycle

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        StyleKit.drawTextButton(frame: rect, buttonLabelText: text)
    }
}
```

[image: ibinspectable]

Since you are already using PaintCode, I would stick to it and do everything you could there.

[Take a look at PaintCode's documentation on using variables](https://www.paintcodeapp.com/documentation/using-variables).

> And here's the Xcode project:
>   https://github.com/backslash-f/paintcode-tests